# dynamic if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to convert a string to a condition inside if statement:

**example:**

```
var condition = "a == b && ( a > 5 || b > 5)";

if(condition) {
    alert("succes");
}
```

Comment: eval or new Function, but that is a bad idea....

Comment: You can technically, but that is not a good practice - Can you add a bit of context to your question? Why do you need that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: https://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A safer alternative to `eval()` may be `Function()`.

```js
var condition = "4 == 4 && ( 10 > 5 || 9 > 5)";
var evaluate = (c) => Function(`return ${c}`)();

if(evaluate(condition)) {
    alert("succes");
}
```

[Per MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

> `eval()` is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run `eval()` with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, a third-party code can see the scope in which `eval()` was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar `Function` is not susceptible.

Comment: Does `Function` used this way alleviate any of `eval()`'s issues?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**new function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
let a = 6;
let b = 6
var condition = "a == b && ( a > 5 || b > 5)";

let func = new Function('a','b', `return (${condition})` )

if(func(a,b)) {
    alert("succes");
}
```

Comment: This one is really great answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` can help, but try to avoid using it

```js
let a = 6;
let b = 6
var condition = "a == b && ( a > 5 || b > 5)";

if (eval(condition)) {
  alert("succes");
}
```

Comment: Agreed, no use eval if possible.

Comment: @MichaelLeVan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @MichaelLeVan [MDN: **Do not ever use `eval()`!**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

Answer (score 0):

use `eval` :

```js
var condition = "4 == 4 && ( 10 > 5 || 9 > 5)";

if(eval(condition)) {
    alert("succes");
}
```

Comment: There's a reason [eval is shunned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data and condition to JSON

Then set the condition by hand:

```js
var json = '{"a":20, "b":20, "max":5}'; //Max is your condition
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var a = data.a;
var b = data.b;
var max = data.max;

if(a == b && ( a > 5 || b > 5)) {
    console.log("foobar");
}
```